# Can you surround an <li> tag with a <div> tag

Tags: html, html-lists

I have some markup and I would like to know if it is proper to surround `<li>` tags with `<div>` tags.

```
  <div class="round3">
    <ul>
      <div class="top"><li class="winner first"></li></div>
      <div class="bottom"><li class="winner last"></li></div>
    </ul>
  </div><!--end round3-->
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: no, inline elements should always be inside block elements

Comment: Why would you need to? You already have the CSS classes on the `li` elements.

Comment: see my comment below to @Mr.Alien

Comment: My markup actually works according to what I want to do. I just know it is not valid markup. But the browsers don't seem to care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not, the only tags that can go directly inside `ul` elements are `li` elements.

You can however, place a `div` inside a `li` element if you wish.

```
<ul>
  <li><div>Example</div></li>
</ul>
```

For more information about HTML lists, see the relevant [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) section.

Comment: thanks @Zenith...I'll come back and accept this as the answer when SO allows me too

Comment: I need to take a different route @Zenith. I need to add borders to my list items. However my list items are draggable and I don't want the borders to go along with them when they are dragged.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.
I propose such correction:

```
  <div class="round3">
    <ul>
      <li class="winner first top"></li>
      <li class="winner last bottom"></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--end round3-->
```

Comment: The erroneous `</div>`s... ***they burn my eyes...***

Comment: That was the way I had the markup as I built the page. I now need to style the list item but in a way outside the item itself. The `<li>`'s are draggable per my jqueryui and I need to add a border to them. I just don't want the border to drag along with the list item.